# Address of WCF Service on remote machine?

Tags: wcf, localhost, remote-server

If I have a machine running a WCF service, what would the address be for it on a different machine on network?

**http://localhost:8080/api/stages** = ???

Answer (score 1):

When you are hosting your WCF Service, you provide address through endpoint. The remote server will use the same address to access your service. For example, consider the following configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="ServiceLib.Services.TaskService">
      <endpoint address="TaskManager"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="ServiceLib.Contracts.ITaskService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <serviceActivations>
      <add service="ServiceLib.Services.TaskService" 
           relativeAddress="TaskService.svc"/>
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In this case, if the service is hosted on IIS with URL of http://localhost:8080/ then the url of your service would be http://localhost:8080/TaskService.svc/TaskManager

Comment: Wow. I think you deciphered my question. Thanks.  Do you have the same details if I was to use my Web API project instead of the WCF?

Comment: Oh.  Is it possible to access the service from a different machine over the network? example: http://[host-name-or-ip]/TaskService.svc/TaskManager ?